# regex in python for alnum

Tags: python, regex

Beginner for regex:
I wanted a regex for alpha numeric string of length 5

where only capital letters or digits could be included

Valid Strings
FCKGW 
A32FD 
 1CF2G 
 etc

Edit to add solution used:
re.match(r'[A-Z0-9]{5}',str)

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive.

Comment: if len(str) == 5 and re.match(r'^[A-Z0-9]$',str)

Comment: @user1007839 `^` and `$` only match beginning until the end of the string. Is that the case or do you want to match multiple times in one string?

Comment: @user1007839 Well, you can do this without the length check... look in the manual to see what `{}` syntax does in re's...

Comment: You can actually check the length in regex. I suggest reading up on [quantifiers](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html).

Comment: I wanted to match multiple times in one string.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A valid regex, which allows only the following charaters: A-Z (uppercase) and 0-9, would be:

```
^[A-Z0-9]{5}$
```

If you want to allow lowercase characters too, the regex would be:

```
^[A-Za-z0-9]{5}$
```

Comment: hey buddy you often have an 'i' tag that will make the thing case insensitive: /^[a-z\d]{5}$/i e.g. I was too slow to answer myself!!

Comment: @d'alar'cop It may work for PHP or other languages but not for Python (and he have asked especially for Python). Doing it in python with adding `re.IGNORECASE` as last argument of match. Example: `re.match(r"^[A-Z0-9]{5}$", "TeStS", re.IGNORECSE`.